# gormでselectして特定の値のjsonを返したい

Tags: go, gorm

```
    import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type UnivNormalTimeTable struct {
    Id           int    `json:"id"`
    Hour         int    `json:"hour"`
    Minute       int    `json:"minute"`
    DayOfTheWeek string `json:"day_of_the_week"`
}

type UnivNormalTimeTables []UnivNormalTimeTable

type UnivNormalTimeTableRepository struct{}

var db *gorm.DB
var err error

func init() {
    db, err = gorm.Open("sqlite3", "data/kamigamo.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&UnivNormalTimeTable{})
}

func NewUnivNormalTimeTableRepository() UnivNormalTimeTableRepository {
    return UnivNormalTimeTableRepository{}
}

func (p UnivNormalTimeTableRepository) LoadKamigamoTime() UnivNormalTimeTables {
    var univNormalTimeTable = UnivNormalTimeTables{}
    db.Select("hour, minute, day_of_the_week").Find(&univNormalTimeTable)
    return univNormalTimeTable
}
```

今、上記のようなモデルを作成しているのですが、idをjsonで返す必要がないため、id以外をselectしています。これを呼び出した結果のjsonが、

```
{
            "id": 0,
            "hour": 9,
            "minute": 5,
            "day_of_the_week": "normal"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "hour": 9,
            "minute": 15,
            "day_of_the_week": "normal"
        },...
```

のような形で返ってきてidが0の状態になってしまいます。idを除いたjsonの返し方を知りたいです。

Answer (score 1):

`UnivNormalTimeTables` 型の変数を使うことにしているため、戻り値の構造体には必ず `Id` フィールドが存在します。このフィールドは構造体を初期化したときに 0 が代入されているので現在の挙動になっています。そこでたとえば、`UnivNormalTimeTables` 型の変数を JSON に変換している部分のコードを変えることで `Id` フィールド無しの JSON を出力することができます。あるいは http://doc.gorm.io/advanced.html#sql-builder のように結果を格納するための構造体を別に作っても良いです。